# Assets with Digests with Nginx, Passenger, Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, passenger

I have a website currently running fine except that I can't figure out how to utilize assets with the digest in their name. It is an Ubuntu server, I use Capistrano to deploy to Rails 3.2, Nginx and Passenger. When I use developer tools in Chrome to look at network requests of our production site, I see that it is only loading `application.js` rather than `application.js-a99ef8tne89....js`. I'd like to use the digest versions as I'm doing lots of updates to assets recently.

I feel like the issue may be my nginx config but unsure...?

My production.rb in Rails:

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
config.serve_static_assets = false

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
config.assets.compress = true

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = false

# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true
```

My nginx.conf file:

```
server {
# PRODUCTION WEB SERVER
  listen 80;
  server_name app.mysite.com;
  root /home/deploy/my_app/current/public;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env production;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/my_app_production.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/my_app_production.error.log;

        location ^~ /assets/ {
                gzip_static on;
                expires max;
                add_header Cache-Control public;
        }
}
```

The site has been up and running great for a while, I just can't figure out why the digest versions of assets aren't being used. I've checked and the digest versions of the assets are deployed to the correct location and the manifest.xml file is also correct. Perhaps this has something to do with the `location ^~ /assets/ {` block above? Thanks for any insight.

Comment: I also wonder if `config.serve_static_assets = false` should perhaps be set to true? But everywhere I've seen it says to keep this set to false since I'm using nginx...

Comment: UPDATE: Actually I tried setting `config.serve_static_assets = true` and then restarting both nginx and passenger and still I'm not seeing digested assets being loaded :-(